# c# error - Input String was not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thanks to the very helpful answers I have been able to modify my page so my dropdown boxes correctly update with the selected results from my SQL query.

The last phase of my testing is to update the changed record into the database.  Regardless of what I do, I keep getting an error - Input string was not in a correct format.

It looks like the text value is being passed instead of the Author's ID - but I have identified the AuthorID in the datavaluefield.   Below is my code:

```
 protected void btnAddAuthors(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    odsIdentifiedAuthors.Insert();
    lbAuthors.ClearSelection();
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }



  protected void groupList_TextSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    lbUserList.Items.Clear();
    lbUserList.Items.Add(new ListItem(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
    lbUserList.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text).Selected = true;
}






  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Author_Name"  EnableViewState="false"
    DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AuthorsList_TextSelected" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Libros %>"         
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Author_Name], [AuthorID] FROM [Authors] WHERE ([Genre] = @Genre)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlAuthors" Name="Genre" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: which line is giving the error?

Comment: The error happens when the btnAddAuthors event is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ControlParameter's ControlID attribute refers to the ID of the DropDownList's, so the two have to match:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAuthors" ...
```

Comment: I've discovered there is a class that this form calls. There are also multiple other variables on this page that are intertwined within its functions.  This will take me a little while to figure out.  Ideally, you solution would work so I am accepting it and the other proposed solution.  Thank you for taking the time to review and respond to my question.

Answer (score 0):

//DataValueField have set as ID. But it should be "AuthorID"

Add this

DataValueField="AuthorID"

Comment: I've discovered there is a class that this form calls. There are also multiple other variables on this page that are intertwined within its functions.  This will take me a little while to figure out.  Ideally, you solution would work so I am accepting it and the other proposed solution.  Thank you for taking the time to review and respond to my question.